# Snowflake: replacing column values

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column that contains both numbers and alphanumeric characters in it. For number values in the column, I am just trying to replace them a different set of numbers. For alphanumeric columns, I am replacing them w/ different letters and numbers. Below are a few values:

select * from t1;

```
1234  
AB145C  
678BC  
8765  
3786CA
```

Below SQL is not working for some reason:

```
select col1,  
case   
when  regexp_like(col1,'^[A-Z]+$')  
then   replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(col1,'A','Z'),'B','Y'),'C','X'),'D','W'),'E','V'),'F','U')  
when try_to_number(col1) is not null  
then round(to_number(col1)*1.5)  
end as col1_replaced  
from t1;
```

what I could be doing wrong here?

Output I'm getting now:

```
COL1    COL1_REPLACED  
1234    1851  
AB145C  NULL  
678BC   NULL  
8765    13148  
3786CA  NULL
```

Desired output:

```
COL1    COL1_REPLACED  
1234    1851  
AB145C  ZY145X  
678BC   678YX  
8765    13148  
3786CA  3786XZ
```

Comment: The multiple nested `REPLACE` could be a single [TRANSLATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/translate.html) call:
`TRANSLATE(col1, 'ABCDEF', 'ZYXWVU')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All branches of a `CASE` expression generally need to have the same type.  Since the first branch is generating text, therefore the `ELSE` branch should also do the same.  You may cast the `ROUND` expression to text here:

```sql
SELECT col1,
       CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(col1, '^[A-Z]+$')
            THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(col1, 'A', 'Z'), 'B', 'Y'), 'C', 'X'), 'D', 'W'), 'E', 'V'), 'F', 'U')
            WHEN TRY_TO_NUMBER(col1) IS NOT NULL
            THEN CAST(ROUND(TO_NUMBER(col1)*1.5) AS VARCHAR(15))
       END AS col1_replaced
FROM t1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes sense. Now, both parts of my case statement are working. However, I still can't make the regexp_like work. I just need to look for alphabets A-Z at the beginning or end of the string, and replace them.

Comment: If you need further help, you should add sample data which explains the additional requirements.

Comment: NO...please do NOT post data here.  Edit your question with proper data.  Thanks.